# Logic of filter json parsing?

Tags: python, json, parsing, filter

I have json object:

```
  photos = {
        "response": {
        "84": {
        "type": "photo",
        "photo": {
          "src_big": "https://pp.userapi.com/xxxx.jpg"
        }
        },
        "49": {
        "type": "photo",
        "photo": {     
          "src_xbig": "https://pp.userapi.com/yyyy.jpg",
          "src_big": "https://pp.userapi.com/xxxx.jpg"
        }
        }
        }
        }
```

I would like to get all links from json object with such filter. 
If 'src_xbig' there is in object I will get it and if not I will get 'src_big'.
Anyway I only can get it with 1 parameter just src_big.

```
  x = photos['response']
  src_big = [x[elem]['photo']['src_big'] for elem in x]
```

How should I filter it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming at least one of `'src_big'` / `'xsrc_big'`is present, you could do:

*Python 3.x*

```
src_big = [x['photo'].get('src_xbig', x['photo']['src_big'])
           for _, x in photos['response'].items()]
```

*Python 2.7*

```
src_big = [x['photo'].get('src_xbig', x['photo']['src_big'])
           for _, x in photos['response'].iteritems()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `'src_big'` is present:

```
photos_response = photos['response']

src_big = list(map(lambda x: photos_response[x]['photo']['src_big'], photos_response))
```

Same with the `src_xbig`